# Entity Framework mapping a Navigation Property as Scalar property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Im trying to generate a model from a database. The model is being generated but all the foreign key fields (that should be only navigation properties) are being mapped as Navigation Property and a scalar property (IN THE MODEL).

I know the foreign key is added in the end of the multiplicity on database but whenever I generate a database from model, all the entity classes doesn't contain that field.

Is there a way to ignore this field generating the model from database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you generate the model from the database there is a check box called *Include foreign key columns in the model*. This check box is by default selected. If you deselect it your model will not contain foreign key properties but just navigation properties.